# C# Outlook VSTO - BeforeAttachmentAdd sometimes is just not fired

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook, vsto

I'm struggling with catching BeforeAttachmentAdd event.
Sometimes it's just not fired, and I don't know why.

There are no exceptions, event is properly registered but it is not fired before adding attachment.
I tried to find out when it is triggered and when not - no luck. Seems completely random to me.

Here's my code:

```
     private Outlook.Application application;
     private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
     private Outlook.Explorer explorer;

     private void NGAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
         this.application = Globals.NGAddIn.Application;
         this.inspectors = this.application.Inspectors;
         this.explorer = application.Explorers.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        
         this.inspectors.NewInspector += NewMailInspector;
     }

     internal static void NewMailInspector(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
     {
         bool isProtectAttachmentEnabled = Properties.Settings.Default.ProtectedAttachment_isEnabled;
         
         Outlook.MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
         if (isProtectAttachmentEnabled && mailItem != null)
         {
             mailItem.BeforeAttachmentAdd += BeforeAttachmentInspector;                
         }
     }

     private static void BeforeAttachmentInspector(Outlook.Attachment attachment, ref bool cancel)
     {
         Outlook.MailItem mailItem = attachment.Parent;            

         if (attachment.Parent is Outlook.MailItem)
         {
             FormPassword formPassword = new FormPassword();

             if (formPassword.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                 string zipFilePath = Zipper.ZipAndProtectAttachment(attachment, formPassword.Password);

                 mailItem.Attachments.Remove(mailItem.Attachments.Count);
                 mailItem.Attachments.Add(zipFilePath);
             }
         }
     }

     private void NGAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {

     }

     #region VSTO generated code

     /// <summary>
     /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
     /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
     /// </summary>
     private void InternalStartup()
     {
         this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(NGAddIn_Startup);
         this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(NGAddIn_Shutdown);
     }

     #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object that raises the events (`mailItem`) is a local variable that can get released by the Garbage Collector at any point after the `NewMailInspector` method exits. No events will be raised after that.

Create a class that wraps the `Inspector` object and make `mailItem` its member. Note that it is not a good idea to just make `mailItem` a global (class) variable in your addin main class since you can have multiple messages open.